# CSS dropdown cuts down

Tags: html, css

In this site http://rgdev.realtyguard.com/ In "Find your dream home!" section I am having problem with dropdown which is cut down when I click on it.

I would like to see the div above the main div.

Find out the following attachment

[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The `#main-slideshow` and `.ls-slide` both have the css property `overflow: hidden` applied to them. Removing this allow the _Min. Bedrooms_ dropdown to overflow and not be cut off. However it also breaks your layout. Time to refactor your CSS I think

Comment: Changing the height of `.ls-wp-fullwidth-container` to `430px` and changing the height of its children to `height: 100%` is one quick workaround to at least show the full dropdown. Your CSS needs a major overhaul in the long term. It is full of redundant properties and impossible to comprehend inline styles!

Answer (score 0):

There is a padding and margin on ul.chosen-results which means that the items dont reach the edge. To remove this all you have to do is add this to your css:

```
.chosen-results {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `margin-right: 0` to:

```
#ihf-main-container ul,
#ihf-main-container ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0;/*add margin right 0*/
}
```